# Javascript Problem on expand images

Tags: javascript, asp.net, treeview, toggle

I have a problem with my TreeView here.

My TreeView is in a UserControl.
On the first page, the UserControl is placed directly on the content page. Everything works finde.

example (working):

```
<a id="MainContent_CategoryTreeView1_TreeView1n209" href="javascript:TreeView_ToggleNode(MainContent_CategoryTreeView1_TreeView1_Data,209,MainContent_CategoryTreeView1_TreeView1n209,&#39; &#39;,MainContent_CategoryTreeView1_TreeView1n209Nodes)">
    <img src="demo.jpg" />
</a>
```

On the second page, the UserControl is placed in a TabContainer (TabPanel). The javascript for expanding does not work.

What i found out is, that the ID of the table cell, the expand image is placed in, differs from the href where the javascript is in.

example (not working):

```
<a id="MainContent_TabContainer_tbPbl_Categories_CategoryTreeView1_TreeView1n209" href="javascript:TreeView_ToggleNode(MainContent_CategoryTreeView1_TreeView1_Data,209,MainContent_CategoryTreeView1_TreeView1n209,&#39; &#39;,MainContent_CategoryTreeView1_TreeView1n209Nodes)">
    <img src="demo.jpg" />
</a>
```

Is that a bug of the ASP.Net TreeView? Any idea how to solve this?

EDIT:

May be interesting too: Whenever the TreeView is loaded first, i build the hierarchy in code and save the rootNode to the Cache. So, my Page Load event looks like:

```
if (CacheFacade.CategoryTreeView == null)
    var rootNode = BuildHierachy();
    CacheFacade.CategoryTreeView = rootNode;
    //databind rootNode to TreeView
else 
    //databind from CacheFacade.CategoryTreeView
```

This is what messes the generated javascript up. 
But why? The javascript has the generated client ID's in it. Isn't that part of the rendering (after the PageLoad) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found out what the problem was here:

In this scenario, it is not possible to store the TreeNodeCollection (or the rootNode) in the Cache.

I thought, it was a clever idea to cache the whole collection to save the time for building the hierachy. But if i try to place the UserControl in another page (in another container), the generated expand/collapse javascript is messed up (Client IDs are not correct).

Well, for the future:

- Cache the data, the TreeView is build upon, yes !
- Cache the rootNode, no !